# Nginx returns html instead of json in Django

Tags: django, angular, nginx, server

I'm trying to deploy an **Angluar and Django** web site on an **Nginx** server. The frontend works properly, but when i make a call to the backend, Django returns me an html response instead of a json response. I searched online, but i can't came out with a solution.

This is the nginx configuration:

```
server {
server_name sub.domain.net www.sub.domain.net;
root /var/www/projectfolder/frontend;
index index.html;

# Handles proxying to Angular App
location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, XMLHttpRequest, Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Type, DNT, If-Modified-Since, Keep-Alive, Origin, User-Agent, X-Mx-ReqToken, X-Requested-With';
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}


# Handles proxying to Django API
location ~* /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This is the Django code:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
        news = News.objects.all().values().order_by('-date')
        
        return Response(news)
```

To this endpoint:

```
/getnews/
```

The server response is:

```
Accept-Ranges:
bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin, XMLHttpRequest, Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Type, DNT, If-Modified-Since, Keep-Alive, Origin, User-Agent, X-Mx-ReqToken, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
*
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
26794
Content-Type:
text/html
Date:
Wed, 16 Aug 2023 12:48:03 GMT
Etag:
"64d6018c-68aa"
Last-Modified:
Fri, 11 Aug 2023 09:38:20 GMT
Server:
nginx/1.22.1
```

Of course on localhost it works properly.
How can I solve this?